# Erdos-Turan theorem for normal subgroups?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, inequality, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $N \triangleleft G$. Let’s define the relative commuting fraction as $$cf(G, N) := \frac{|\{(g, h) \in G \times H| [g, h] = e\}|}{|G||H|}$$

Does there exist such $\epsilon > 0$, that for all $G$ and $H$ if $cf(G, N) > 1 - \epsilon$, then $N \leq Z(G)$?

For the particular case when $N = G$ we have the following fact:

**Erdos-Turan theorem**

> If $cf(G, G) > \frac{5}{8}$, then $G$ is abelian.

However, the [method that is used to prove it](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Commuting_fraction_more_than_five-eighths_implies_abelian) can not be extended onto this general case…

It may still be useful to get this inequality:

> $$cf(G, N) \leq \frac{|Z(G) \cap N|}{|N|} + \frac{1}{2}$$

$$cf(G, N) = \frac{1}{|G||H|}(|G||Z(G)\cap N| + \Sigma_{g \in N} C_G(g)) \leq \frac{1}{|G||H|}(|G||Z(G)\cap N| + \frac{|N||G|}{2}) = \frac{|Z(G) \cap N|}{|N|} + \frac{1}{2}$$

But I do not know how to proceed further...

Comment: If you replace $Z$ with $Z\cap N$ and $G\setminus Z$ with $N\setminus (Z\cap N)$ which step doesn't work? (The assumption at the start should obviously be $N\not\le Z$ which is equivalent to $N\ne Z\cap N$)

Comment: @Robert Chamberlain, the step, when we use $[G: Z(G)] \geq 4$. I do not see, why it should work with $[N: N\cap Z(G)]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done most the work finding the above bound, but you made one subtle error.

The sum should be over $g\in N\setminus(Z(G)\cap N)$.

If you follow this through you get
$$cf(G,N)\le\frac{|Z(G)\cap N|}{2|N|}+\frac{1}{2}$$

So if $cf(g,N)>3/4$ then $\frac{|Z(G)\cap N|}{|N|}>\frac{1}{2}$ and $Z(G)\cap N=N$